# My Python 'IF' statements are ignored

Tags: python, arrays, variables, if-statement, return

Sorry that this is a bit of an amateur question, but i can't see what i'm doing wrong here, and it always helps if you get someone else to look at your code!

So i want people to be sorted into a different house depending on their birth month, and my string is being sliced at the right point (confirmed with a quick test in the interactive prompt) but house is always set to the else statement - which shouldn't happen...

Any help will be much appreciated!

(please ignore the append_to_file function also - just focusing on the get_user_inputs function)

(Text wouldn't format properly so i had to link to pastebin:)

CODE IS HERE https://pastebin.com/DzkeZ8bq

```
had to put code for a pastebin link so have a print statement

print("You're awesome if you help me!")
```

FURTHER EXPLAINATION:

So say if the following test data is used:

- firstName = "Joe"
- lastName = "Bloggs"
- dateOfBirth = "10/05/2002"

It should sort Joe Bloggs into Saturn house (as dateOfBirth[3:5] is '05', meaning that '05' is in the list 'sat')

But instead, Joe Bloggs is sorted into Mars house (because the else statement has no condition, so my code seems to be defaulting to that.)

Again, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of sending us to an external link

Comment: First: to format code, copy-paste it into the question box, then select all the code (including the parts that look okay in the preview) and hit Ctrl-K or the button with the braces. Second: too much code. Give us a [mcve].

Comment: Stop trying to compare booleans to `False` or `True`. It's unnecessary, and the precedence doesn't work the way you're expecting it to.

Comment: Why are you importing in the middle of your code? `import` statements belong at the top, before any functions. Also, that's a bit much code to paste, you might want to try making a [mcve] with emphasis on the *minimal*..

Comment: 1) Sorry, i couldn't get the code to format properly so Stack Overflow wouldn't accept it - hence why i gave a pastebin link

Comment: 2) As above, sorry

Comment: 3) Thanks, you and sunny provided a working solution!

Comment: 4) I know it's bad practice, but i usually work scruffy and then neaten up code at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing

```
if dateOfBirth[3:5] in nep == True:
```

To

```
if dateOfBirth[3:5] in nep:
```